# redirect from one domain to another but keep requested page

Tags: drupal, redirect

I want to create a redirect for one of my domains to another.
I followed what reported [in this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18347/how-to-redirect-all-urls-to-a-new-domain), and it works just fine.

The problem I'm having now is that I want to redirect www.example.com/some-page to
www.new-example.com/some-page.

Right now, www.example.com/some-page just redirects to www.new-example.com, this could be confusing for users who created bookmarks to some parts of the website.

Both URLs link to the same webhosting, and I'm running a litespeed server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Edit: yourdomain.com should be the domain you wanna redirect to.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I added the rule but it did not seem to work. I changed the rule to this:    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http ://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] and that did work.

Any ideas why? Thanks again!